# How to recognize negative numbers in node.js Buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js

Suppose say I want to create a node.js Buffer for the array `[-1, 255, 3, 4]`

```
var i = new Buffer([-1, 255, 3, 4])
```

For negative numbers, it will just take two's complement and store it as is. So here:

```
console.log(i)
<Buffer ff ff 03 04>
```

Also,

```
console.log(i.toJSON())
{ type: 'Buffer', data: [ 255, 255, 3, 4 ] }
```

Is there a way to distinguish negative numbers from positive ones?

Comment: There is no negative numbers in `Buffer`. Each value in `Buffer` is a byte - an unsigned 8-bit value. You can't recognise something that is not there.

Comment: ^ This as an answer, sir.

Comment: @Amadan Hmm, your reply should actually have been posted as an answer.

Comment: Consider zigzag encode/decode to convert signed numbers to unsigned. https://gist.github.com/mfuerstenau/ba870a29e16536fdbaba

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @Amadan point out in the comment,

> There is no negative numbers in `Buffer`. Each value in `Buffer` is a **byte** - an **unsigned 8-bit value**. You can't recognise something that is not there

When read data from buffer, there are `unsigned` method, such as `readUInt8()`; and `signed` method, such as `readInt8()`.

```
> var i = new Buffer([-1, 255, 3, 4])
undefined
> i.readInt8(0)
-1
> i.readInt8(1)
-1
> i.readUInt8(1)
255
> i.readUInt8(0)
255
```